# Specifying attributes for network dataset?

Tags: arcgis-9.3, routing, network-analyst, arcgis-desktop, references

Using ArcGIS 9.3 to try and create some routes with network analyst... currently following this tutorial: [Network analyst tutorial for 9.3](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Network_Analyst_Tutorial)

I have a street dataset from NYS clearinghouse. I can't seem to figure out how to add the FT_minutes attribute. Not sure if I can build routes based on time without it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Calculate length of each segment then assign an average speed to the class of each (minor is less, highways are more) use Field Calculator for new fields FT & TF Minutes = Distance/KPH or MPH. your need FT_minutes & TF_minutes for two-way traffic.

Comment: Are you having issue with assigning the attribute to the line features, or within the Network Dataset?

Comment: Are you still using ArcGIS 9.3 to try and do this? If not, what ArcGIS for Desktop version are you using? What have you tried to do so far? You can use the edit button beneath your Question to revise it with these details.